# flask how to go from single to multi-tenant

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a working flask app (sqlalchemy, mysql) that I made for one company (tenant). I would like to now expand it for use by other companies. I am, however, finding it difficult to find a good flask example/code/guide on how to implement this. Ideally, I would like either:

1. Separate database per tenant
2. Shared database but with separate schemas per tenant (something like https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas but for flask)

Please help!

Comment: You do not want a separate database per tenant even if it seems like a good idea today. One day you'll have a simple schema change that turns into a nightmare because you have to run it thousands of times, once on each database.

Comment: Yes, approach #2 for flask would be ideal.

Comment: It's usually best to just add a context identifier for each tenant, could even be as simple as adding `tenant_id` to any records that are tenant specific, adjusting your indexes, and always including this in any scopes.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid altering all my tables, but it seems a shared database and shared schema may be the best solution for now. Do I just create a new model called Tenant and then add a ForeignKey field to my other models pointing to the Tenant model?

Comment: That's the general idea. You will have to modify your database, switching to a multi-tenant structure is not something you can do without that. The thing is it's usually not a big deal, as only certain types of records will need that field. For example, normally it's users, projects, accounts, and anything that hangs off of those, relationally speaking, won't be affected.

Comment: where you able to find one? @spitz